# Parsing JSON Arrays with PHP

Tags: php, json, api, curl

Trying to parse a JSON API array result using PHP / CURL. Can retrieve the JSON without an issue but finding quite difficult to parse any data I want from the returned JSON. Using the below PHP code.

```
    <?php
    $url = "https://openlibrary.org/search.json?q=green+eggs+and+ham&page=1";

    $headers = array(
    "Content-type: application/json;charset=\"utf-8\"",
    "Accept: text/xml",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Pragma: no-cache",
    "SOAPAction: \"run\""
      ); 

     $cURL = curl_init();

     curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
     curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
     curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


     $result = curl_exec($cURL);

     //print_r($result);

     foreach (json_decode($result, true) as $book) {

     echo '<p><h3>';
     echo 'title : '.$book['docs']['title_suggest'];
     echo 'author : '.$book['docs']['author_name'].'<br />';
     echo 'pubdate : '.$book['docs]['publish_date'].'<br />';
     echo 'isbn: '.$book['docs']['ia'][0].'<br />';
     echo '</h3></p>';

     }

     curl_close($cURL);
     ?>
```

Help much appreciated!  Cheers!

Comment: We can't help without seeing the JSON you are trying to decode...

Comment: Or why you thought the outmost layer was an array.

Comment: PD of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](//stackoverflow.com/q/29308898)

Comment: Or dump ouput of JSON or Array and write what difficulties you are facing? Also write your desire output to help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Decode the JSON data 1st $obj_data = json_decode($result);
2. Close the Curl when the operation is complete.
3. For best practice receive data till "docs" and loop over it.
   This will help you!

   ```
    
   $url = "https://openlibrary.org/search.json?q=green+eggs+and+ham&page=1";
   ```

   $headers = array(
       "Content-type: application/json;charset=\"utf-8\"",
       "Accept: text/xml",
       "Cache-Control: no-cache",
       "Pragma: no-cache",
       "SOAPAction: \"run\""
   );

   $cURL = curl_init();

   curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
   curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

   $result = curl_exec($cURL);
   curl_close($cURL);
   //Json Data decoded on PHP object
   $obj_data = json_decode($result);
   foreach ($obj_data->docs as $book) {
       //fetch object data
       echo 'title : '.$book->title_suggest;
       echo 'author : '.$book->author_name[0];
       echo 'pubdate : '.$book->publish_date;
       echo 'isbn: '.$book->ia[0];
   }

Comment: the JSON wanting to parse is the following -> https://openlibrary.org/search.json?q=the+lord+of+the+rings&page=2